# WebWorker path import in Vite

Tags: vuejs3, vite, vue-composition-api

I'm currently developing a Vue.js library using Vite as the build tool. In development mode, everything works perfectly, and the web workers are imported with the intended path:

Example (**Development** Mode):
Worker's Path: http://localhost:5173/src/components/datatable/workerCreateDatatableList.js?type=module&worker_file=
Result: The worker is successfully loaded.

However, I'm facing an issue when trying to import the library in a project and building it for production. The web worker paths seem to be incorrect:

Example (**Production** Mode):
Worker's Path: http://localhost:3000/assets/workerRegroupWorker-7b23b61a.js
Result: The worker doesn't exist inside the assets folder. This is expected since workers are only available inside the node_modules/cp/assets/ directory.

I'm not sure how to resolve this problem and ensure that the web workers are correctly imported in the production build.

## Project Structure:

- cp
- - package.json
- - vite.config.ts
- - - src
- - - - components
- - - - - datatable
- - - - - - dt.vue
- - - - - - workerCreateDatatableList.js <- Imported inside dt.vue
- - - - - - workerRegroupWorker.js <- Imported inside dt.vue
- - - - - - workerSelectRows.js <- Imported inside dt.vue

## package.json

```
  "name": "cp",
  "private": true,
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "type": "module",
  "files": ["dist"],
  "main": "./dist/lib.umd.cjs",
  "module": "./dist/lib.js",
  "exports": {
    ".": {
      "import": "./dist/lib.js",
      "require": "./dist/lib.umd.cjs"
    }
  },
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "vite",
    "build": "vue-tsc && vite build",
    "preview": "vite preview"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "node-sass": "^9.0.0",
    "primevue": "^3.31.0",
    "sass": "^1.64.1",
    "sass-loader": "^13.3.2",
    "vue": "^3.3.4",
    "vue-router": "4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@vitejs/plugin-vue": "^4.2.3",
    "typescript": "^5.0.2",
    "vite": "^4.4.5",
    "vue-tsc": "^1.8.5"
  }
}
```

## vite.config.ts

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue'
import { resolve } from 'path'
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'


// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [vue()],
  build: {
    lib: {
      // Could also be a dictionary or array of multiple entry points
      entry: resolve(__dirname, 'libmain.js'),
      name: 'improvizelib',
      // the proper extensions will be added
      fileName: 'lib',
    },
    rollupOptions: {
      // make sure to externalize deps that shouldn't be bundled
      // into your library
      external: ['vue'],
      output: {
        // Provide global variables to use in the UMD build
        // for externalized deps
        globals: {
          vue: 'Vue',
        },
      },
    },
  },
})
```

## dt.vue ( only the import section )

```
const createDatatableList = new Worker(new URL("./workerCreateDatatableList.js?worker", import.meta.url ), {
  type: 'module',
});
const regroupWorker = new Worker(new URL("./workerRegroupWorker.js?worker", import.meta.url ), {
  type: 'module',
});
const workerSelectRows = new Worker(new URL("./workerSelectRows.js?worker", import.meta.url ));
```

I attempted to modify the URL import as follows:

const createDatatableList = new Worker("./workerCreateDatatableList.js?worker", {
type: 'module',
});

However, my attempt was not successful.

My question is : How can I correctly import Web Workers inside dt.vue so that the web workers have the right path during the build process ?

Comment: We use [this rollup plugin](https://github.com/darionco/rollup-plugin-web-worker-loader) to inline our worker file. Just be sure to watch your bundle size!

Answer (score 0):

I've had the exact same problem. Although maybe not the ideal solution, this issue can be fixed by adding `&inline` to the import of your Worker-file. I've tried the following which does work in my case:

`import Worker from "./MyWorker.worker?worker&inline";`

Note: my Worker-file is called: `MyWorker.worker.ts` (note the extra `.worker` which you can also omit).

Comment: I will try on my project ty.